# Django -- order model records based on criteria?

Tags: django, django-models

When I build a model in Django, I add the following information:

```
def __unicode__(self):
  return self.some_field

class Meta:
  ordering = ['some_field_to_order_by']
```

Is it possible to set `ordering` based on a sort of `if/else` scenario?

For example, I have a `customer` model which, for sake of argument, has these fields:

```
first_name
last_name
company_name
is_company (boolean)
```

If the `customer` is a Company, I only add information to the `company_name` field and set `is_company=True`, leaving the other two blank. If the `customer` is a person, then I add information to the `first_name` and `last_name` fields, leaving the `company_name` blank and the `is_company=False`.

I want to sort these records by `last_name` if the `is_company` field is `False` and `company_name` if `is_company` is `True`.

Is this possible?

**EDIT For an example (per request, sort of)**

For my app, this `customer` table holds information regarding owners of security systems. Sometimes, a security system is installed in a residential setting. In this case, the owner of the system is a person -- thus, I would enter the `first_name` and `last_name` into the `customer` record. Sometimes the system is installed in a commercial setting, therefore the owner is a company. For this I enter only the `company_name` field, leaving the other fields blank.

Now, when I provide an estimate for a NEW security system installation, I can provide the estimate to a new customer or an existing customer (existing customer, but a new location for them). When it is an existing customer, I have a drop down box that lists all existing customers (ALL RECORDS in the `customer` table).

THIS is where I want all the records to be ordered properly. As it is now, I get a jumbled mess of hundreds of records making it brutal to find the existing owner.

Hopefully this helps with what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: of course. add an explicit order_by call to your queryset. setting this in your meta class, even if you find a way to do it, makes little sense because meta defines ordering for the whole table which is a collection containing both companies and persons.

Comment: @akonsu -- I virtually always show all the records, not just persons or just companies -- all companies and all persons together. That's why I want to figure out a way to get the ordering done without defining it in the `queryset`.

Comment: please clarify then how do you want to order a queryset that contains both companies and people?

Comment: basically you want to order by a custom function. I think django cannot do it unless you write a raw query. here is a link to the same question: http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/9f84caa888c31315. I would use the same field for both people names and companies names and sort by it. Yes, this is not perfect, but installing a custom function to the database during deployent I think is worse.

Comment: @akonsu -- thanks for the replies. I had thought for Companies I could just add the same data to `last_name` as is held in `company_name`. The problem is that if the user changes the value in `company_name` then I would have to update the `last_name` field too. I was hoping for a more elegant way of solving this problem.

Comment: I mean I would have a single field for both the company name and the last name. no need to synchronise two fields.

Comment: @akonsu -- holy smokes.... why did I not think of that. In other words, scrap the `company_name` field, and JUST use `last_name` for companies. Brilliant. You see, THAT is the type of elegant solution I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom manager, which will do what you want.

```
class CompanyFilter(models.Manager):
   def get_query_set(self):
        qs = super(CompanyFilter, self).get_query_set()
        return qs.filter(is_company=True).order_by('company_name')

class PersonFilter(models.Manager):
   def get_query_set(self):
        qs = super(PersonFilter, self).get_query_set()
        return qs.filter(is_company=False).order_by('last_name')

class Contact(models.Model):
   # ... your regular fields

   companies = CompanyFilter()
   people = PersonFilter()


all_companies = Contact.companies.all()
all_people = Contact.people.all()
all_contacts = Contact.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

1 . assuming that either of the fields is always `NULL` you can use `extra` query:

```
  MyModel.objects
    .extra(select=dict(name='coalesce(last_name, company_name)'))
    .order_by('name')
```

(`COALESCE` seems to be supported in all major database engines)

2 . or simply eliminate either `last_name` or `company_name` and put last names and company names in to the same field and sort by it.